# Rails 5 - Replacing find_by :id with another param

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to make it so /cards/:id is rendered as another param instead - multiverse_id is the name within my DB.

So I tried replacing

```
    def show
   # @card = Card.where(multiverse_id: params[:multiverse_id])
    @card = Card.find(params[:id])
  end
```

However, while using it the view fails at every reference of @card (Which I kind of expected).

I'm not too familiar with how to fix routes to modify it to use :multiverse_id instead.

I also need to have a fallback -to- use ID if multiverse_id doesn't exist (I have ~2,000) of this scenario.

```
def show
    if Card.where(multiverse_id: params[:multiverse_id]).nil?
      @card = Card.find(params[:id])
    else
      @card = Card.where(multiverse_id: params[:multiverse_id])
    end
   # @card = Card.find(params[:id])
  end
```

I tried this logic but I got the same error. I'm unsure if this logic will work since the route will look for cards/:id

Welcome any input

**UPDATE**

I tried the Permalink suggestions but it didn't seem to take any effect - Each type I checked ActiveDirectory was only looking up :id, no matter what.

I did take the suggestion of using

```
 def show
    if Card.where(multiverse_id: params[:multiverse_id]).nil?
      @card = Card.find(params[:id])
    else
      @card = Card.find_by(multiverse_id: params[:multiverse_id])
    end
   # @card = Card.find(params[:id])
  end
```

But it's still returning the :id every time - I did notice ActiveDirectory is querying `multiverse_id`, but it runs

```
  Card Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "cards".* FROM "cards" WHERE "cards"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 15634], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Card Load (2.0ms)  SELECT  "cards".* FROM "cards" WHERE "cards"."multiverse_id" IS NULL LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 1]]
```

Which isn't really what I need. Should I change the logic?

**Update Again**

```
  def show
    @card = Card.find_by_multiverse_id(params[:multiverse_id]) if params[:multiverse_id]
    @card = Card.find(params[:id]) unless @card.present?

   # @card = Card.find(params[:id])
  end
```

But isn't :id always going to be getting passed base on the routes?

But after thinking more about it my need mind need to be asked differently.

**My Concern**

Some cards won't have Multiverse_IDs as I mentioned, so I wanted those to roll back to :id. However, currently some of my IDs are equal to multiverse IDs - Which would cause an issue. Is it possible for me to re-populate my DB and in the rake somehow force the ID to be equal to :multiverse_id if it exists, if not, become id?

**My Rake**

```
namespace :cards do 
    desc "Create cards"
    task :create_cards => :environment do
        cards = MTG::Card.all
        cards.each do |card|
            puts card.name + '-' + card.set
            card.image_url.blank? ? image_url = "/assets/mtgCardBack.jpg" : image_url = card.image_url
            Card.create(
                ...
                multiverse_id: card.multiverse_id, 
                ...
                )
        end
    end
end
```

It populated much more but that's the only constant.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Here , your where condition will return active record array. try to use find_by instead of where.

Answer (score 1):

Try this in your controller :

```
@book = Book.find_by_multiverse_id(params[:multiverse_id]) if params[:multiverse_id]

@book = Book.find(params[:id]) unless @book.present?
```

Comment: This seems to not be working as intended for me. Is it a routing issue since the route is expecting cards/:id ?

`  def show
    @card = Card.find_by_permalink(params[:multiverse_id]) if params[:multiverse_id] 
    
    @card = Card.find(params[:id]) unless @card.present?
  end`

Comment: Please try with updated answer. And also paste your error log here, if you found any issue.

Comment: Rather* Removing the 'if params[:multiverse_id]' from the first part makes it work but I have an issue

Answer (score 0):

one way to make it work is parameterize `permalink` with `to_param` method on your `Card` model

```
class Card < ApplicationRecord
  def to_param
    permalink
  end
  ...
end
```

Then, on your controller, something like this to use either permalink or id:

```
if params[:permalink]
  @book = Book.find_by_permalink(params[:permalink])
else
  @book = Book.find(params[:id])
end
```